# How to write this table format as its shown in the picture

Tags: tables

[image]

I want to use this table format in my work. I have tried to implement it, but I have been unable to obtain the same result. Please help me to access the code of this table format.

Comment: Welcome! What have you tried? Please give us a starting point :) Having said that, you'll need a `tabular`, a `multicolumn`, and some horizontal lines.

Comment: I found the solution of the problem. Dozens of thanks for immediate reply

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

Here's how I'd do it. It needs a few tweaks, but hopefully this will get you pointed in the right direction. I recommend taking a look at some of the packages I've used. They probably have some useful functionality for some of the sort of tables you seem to be trying to produce.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs} % Adds table formatting options
\usepackage{dcolumn} % Adds option to align data around the decimal point
\newcolumntype{d}{D{.}{.}{-1}} % Use 'd' to align column on decimal place
\usepackage[labelfont={bf},singlelinecheck={off}]{caption} % Formats captions on images, tables, etc.
\newcommand{\cc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}} % centralise table cell

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[tp]
    \centering
    \caption{caption text goes here}
    \label{tbl:crossref-label}
    \begin{tabular}{l d d @{\extracolsep{6pt}} d d l}
        \toprule
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{multicolumn title} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{multicolumn title} \\
        \cmidrule{2-3} \cmidrule{4-6}
        & \cc{Mean} & \cc{SD} & \cc{Mean} & \cc{SD} & \cc{$p$} \\
        \midrule
        text &&&&& \\
        more text & 12.34 & 1.234 & 1.23 & 1.234 & ** \\
        more text & 1.23 & 1.2345 & 12.3 & 1.23 & ** \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This will display like this:
[image: result]

Comment: You can use `\cmidrule` instead of `\cline` to get the same vertical distances as `\midrule`.

Comment: Thanks. That's a better solution. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Here are some hints about how to customize the table as shown in the question:

- `\captionsetup{justification=centering, labelfont=bf, labelsep=quad}`
  to customize the caption as shown above.
- Equalized column widths is best handled by defining a new column type
  using `\newcolumntype{C}{ >{ \arraybackslash \Centering } X }` in the
  preamble where `C` is the new column type. Or you can use `\newcolumntype{R}{ >{ \arraybackslash \RaggedLeft } X }` where `R` is a new column type where entries are justified to the right. Many publications use such format for the first column.
- `\cmidrule(lr){col}` allows for trimmed rulings from left and right
- `\colorbox{LightBlue}{text}` to highlight in the color shown above

The overall code is:

```
\documentclass{report}


% Text justification package
\usepackage{ragged2e}


% Table packages
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

    % New column types
    \newcolumntype{C}{ >{ \arraybackslash \Centering } X } % centered
    \newcolumntype{L}{ >{ \arraybackslash \RaggedRight } X } % left justified
    \newcolumntype{R}{ >{ \arraybackslash \RaggedLeft } X } % right justified
    \newcolumntype{S}[1]{ >{ \arraybackslash \Centering } m{#1} } % centered with specified width


% Caption package
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=centering, labelfont=bf, labelsep=quad} % centers floats caption, makes float name in bold font, and adds space between float name and the caption

% Highlighting packages
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

    % Shortcut command for highlighting in LightBlue
    \newcommand{\LB}[1]{\colorbox{LightBlue}{#1}}



\begin{document}



\begin{table}[htp]


    % Center the table
    \centering

    \caption{Scholarly works, time allocation, satisfaction, and income by US-versus foreign-born status}
    \label{tbl:crossref-label}


    \begin{tabularx}{1\textwidth}{C >{\hsize=0.2\hsize}C >{\hsize=0.2\hsize}C >{\hsize=0.2\hsize}C >{\hsize=0.2\hsize}C >{\hsize=0.2\hsize}C }


        \toprule[0.8pt]


        &
        \multicolumn{2}{S{0.9in}}{Born in US N = $2900^{*}$} &
        \multicolumn{3}{S{1.4in}}{Foreign Born N = $1190$}
        \\
        \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-6}


        & Mean & SD & Mean & SD & $p$
        \\
        \midrule


        Recent Scholarly Works & & & & &
        \\


        \LB{Refereed Articles} & \LB{12.34} & \LB{1.234} & \LB{1.23} & \LB{1.234} & \LB{**}
        \\



        \bottomrule[0.8pt]



    \end{tabularx}


\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using @Ulysses answer as missing MWE in question .., , packages `siunitx` and `threeparttable` for `S` column type and for limit table caption to table width and eventually add table notes below table for example for description of `**` in last column (it is not clear what they meaning) respectively:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs, threeparttable} 
\usepackage{siunitx} % Formats units, numbers, numbers in table
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf, skip=1ex]{caption} % Formats captions of floats
\newcommand{\mcx}[2]{\multicolumn{#1}{c}{#2}} % shortcut for multicolumn

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Scholarly works, time allocation, satisfaction, and income by US-versus foreign-born status}
    \label{tbl:crossref-label}
\begin{tabular}{l *{2}{S[table-format=2.2] S[table-format=1.4]} c}
    \toprule
            & \mcx{2}{multicolumn title}    & \mcx{3}{multicolumn title}    \\
    \cmidrule(lr) {2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-6}
            & {Mean}    & {SD}              & {Mean}    & {SD}  & $p$       \\
    \midrule
text        &           &                   &           &       &           \\
more text   & 12.34     & 1.234             & 1.23      & 1.234 & **        \\
more text   & 1.23      & 1.2345            & 12.3      & 1.23  & **        \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
    \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]